# Search database for matching results, using PHP and MYSQLI

Tags: php, database, search, mysqli

I am kind of new to all of this trying to figure out why things work and why things don't.

So I was aiming for a simple search form to display all of the database users with the same first name.

This code outputs all the names of the users in my table "users" and it works.

```
<?php
include 'connect.php'; //working connection to the DB


$sql="SELECT name FROM users ORDER BY name ASC";

$sqlresult=mysqli_query($con,$sql);

$afct=mysqli_affected_rows($con);

while($user=mysqli_fetch_array($sqlresult,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){ 
    $num[]=$user['name'];
    $num++;
}

$i=1;

while($i < $afct)
{
    echo $i.': '.$num[$i];
    echo'<br>';
    $i++;

}
?>
```

So now I wanted to add a variable that stores the user input, to match with the users first name.

```
<?php
include 'connect.php';    //working connection to the DB

$input = 'Marcus';       // later will be $input = $_GET(['name']);

$sql="SELECT name FROM users WHERE name='".$input."'  ORDER BY name ASC"; 

//tried with "SELECT * FROM users WHERE name='".$input."'" ORDER BY name ASC";
//also

$sqlresult=mysqli_query($con,$sql);

$afct=mysqli_affected_rows($con);

while($user=mysqli_fetch_array($sqlresult,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){ 
    $num[]=$user['name'];
    $num++;
}

$i=1;

while($i < $afct)
{
    echo $i.': '.$num[$i];
    echo'<br>';
    $i++;

}
?>
```

And all it dose is output a blank and sexy page. Thank You in Advance.

//Marcus

Comment: `mysqli_affected_rows` is only used for queries that modify the database. For `SELECT`, you should use `mysqli_num_rows`.

Comment: I don't see why you need `$afct`. Use `count($num)` to get the size of the array, or just loop over it with `foreach`.

Comment: What does `var_dump($sqlresult)` show? If it's `false`, you need to print `$con->error` to see the reason for the SQL error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you initialize `$i` to 1. Array indexes in PHP start at 0, just like almost every other programming language. Since your second query only returns 1 row, the only element will be `$num[0]`. So you should initialize `$i` to 0.

Or use `foreach`:

```
foreach ($num as $i => $name) {
    echo "$i: $name<br>";
}
```

Your first script was also wrong, you just didn't notice that it skipped one of the users in the table.

Answer (score 0):

i think that the second while didn't run because of `$i=1` try with `while($i <= $afct)`

Comment: You were right about $i=1, because I only had one user by the name of Marcus, thanks